# SL 5 out of browser - 1pixel white border?

Tags: silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

I have a SL 5 app set to run out of browser.
The OOB setting:

```
<WindowSettings Title="Thing" Height="497" Width="462" WindowStyle="BorderlessRoundCornersWindow" />
```

Blend reports the width and height for the UserControl as 463, 500.
When the app runs out-of-browser, it appears there is a 1 pixel line of white along the left and top edges.
Some xaml:

```
       <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="500" >
    <Border  BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="6" Padding="2" Background="#FFF17A35">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,4,6">
                <HyperlinkButton
                    <!--blah blah -->
                </HyperlinkButton>
                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hyperlinkCloseButton"
                    <!--blah blah -->
                </HyperlinkButton>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <!--blah blah -->
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <ScrollViewer Width="400" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" MaxHeight="76">
                <TextBlock x:Name="DbgOutput" 
              Text="{Binding DbgMsgTxt}"
               Width="396" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image]
Any hints on where the whiteness is coming from?

Comment: Have you tried setting background & cie to your LayoutRoot Grid to non default values (ie Transparent)?

Answer (score 1):

I Think Fllow This Staps And Helpfull To You My Be

Have New Idea To Implement This

1 . Click On Sliverlight Project

2 . Select Properties option

3 . Select First tab option Like Silverlight

4 . Click On Out-Of-Browser setting Option

[image]